# Floating number not showing up?

Tags: java, floating-point

I have to make a program for my java class that rolls 2 dice, then compares the sum of their observed percentage of appearance compared to the expected percentage of appearance. The observed percentage is expected to be rounded to do decimal places. However, whenever I run the program the observed percentage always comes out as "%.2fn,[percentage]". Here's my (admittedly somewhat messy) code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problem1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random roll1 = new Random();
    Random roll2 = new Random();
    int die1;
    int die2;
    int sum;
    double zero = 0;
    double one = 0;
    double two = 0;
    double three = 0;
    double four = 0;
    double five = 0;
    double six = 0;
    double seven = 0;
    double eight = 0;
    double nine = 0;
    double ten = 0;
    double[] occurances = new double [11];
    double[] percentages = new double [11];
    percentages[0] = 2.78;
    percentages[1] = 5.56;
    percentages[2] = 8.33;
    percentages[3] = 11.11;
    percentages[4] = 13.89;
    percentages[5] = 16.67;
    percentages[6] = 13.89;
    percentages[7] = 11.11;
    percentages[8] = 8.33;
    percentages[9] = 5.56;
    percentages[10] = 2.78;
    System.out.print("How many times would you like to roll the dice? ");
    int repeat = keyboard.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
        die1 = roll1.nextInt(6);
        die2 = roll2.nextInt(6);
        sum = die1 + die2;
        if (sum == 0) {
            zero++;
            occurances[0] = zero;
        } else if (sum == 1) {
            one++;
            occurances[1] = one;
        } else if (sum == 2) {
            two++;
            occurances[2] = two;
        } else if (sum == 3) {
            three++;
            occurances[3] = three;
        } else if (sum == 4) {
            four++;
            occurances[4] = four;
        } else if (sum == 5) {
            five++;
            occurances[5] = five;
        } else if (sum == 6) {
            six++;
            occurances[6] = six;
        } else if (sum == 7) {
            seven++;
            occurances[7] = seven;
        } else if (sum == 8) {
            eight++;
            occurances[8] = eight;
        } else if (sum == 9) {
            nine++;
            occurances[9] = nine;
        } else if (sum == 10) {
            ten++;
            occurances[10] = ten;
        }//if

    }//for

    System.out.println("roll      observed      expected");
    for (int i = 0; i < occurances.length; i++) {
        float observed = (float)(occurances[i]/repeat) * 100;
        System.out.println((i+2)+"         %.2fn"+observed+"%     "+percentages[i]+"%");
    }

}

}
```

How can I get rid of the "%.2fn," before each of the expected percentage and make it only have 2 decimal places? I thought `%.2fn` was the proper notation for that kind of thing, but it's not working for this.

Comment: Why do you have `double zero = 0`? Why not just `occurrences[0]++`;? You don't need a specific variable for every array entry.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Ohmygosh thanks so much for pointing that out, haha. I feel so dumb for overlooking that.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there. If you want to shorten your code with another 50%: you don't need a switch statement. Simply use `occurrences[sum]++;`, it will already select the correct index based on `sum`. And another tip: you don't need two `random` instances. In fact, you don't want that! Just use one, it's perfectly suited for that. Additionally: you can inline multiple variables like this `int die1, die2, sum;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `println` method doesn't know anything about formatting patterns such as `%.2f`; it thinks that's the literal string you want to print.

Look into [the `printf` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead, which understands formatting patterns.

Comment: When I change `println` to `printf` it gives me this error message: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.DuplicateFormatFlagsException: Flags = ' '
 at java.util.Formatter$Flags.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.flags(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
 at Problem1.main(Problem1.java:66)` and I honestly have no idea what that means.

Comment: The `%` character is special to `printf`, meaning, here's a placeholder for a value to format.  So `%` by itself won't print an actual `%` sign.  To support printing a literal `%`, printf supports the format `%%` to produce a single `%`.